# Why doesn't jest.spyOn() sometimes work on a Vue component's method?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I see the changes the method makes as event handler, but `jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'methodName')` doesn't catch the call in major cases, but in some tests it somehow works. I suspect a possible re-render (maybe, due to `options` argument in `mount()` call), that replaces the original method with the `jest.spyOn()`, because, if I trigger event twice in a row, `toHaveBeenCalled()` fulfills and tracks the call.

**The component:**

```
<template>
  <v-app-bar
    app
    color="primary"
    dark
    class="header"
  >
    <router-link
      :to="{name: 'User'}"
      class="up-and-down-link"
    >
      <v-toolbar-title>Тестовое задание</v-toolbar-title>
    </router-link>
    <v-spacer />
    <v-toolbar-items>
      <v-btn
        v-if="isLoggedIn"
        class="button-log-out"
        text
        @click="showLogOutModal"
      >
        Выйти из профиля
      </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
    <Modal
      v-bind="modal"
      @close="onModalClose"
      @click:outside="onModalClose(false)"
    >
      Вы уверены, что хотите выйти из профиля?
    </Modal>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<script>
import { LOG_OUT } from '@/store/auth/action-types';
import { IS_LOGGED_IN } from '@/store/auth/getter-types';
import Modal from '@/components/Modal.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Header',
  components: { Modal },
  data() {
    return {
      modal: {
        show: false,
        withConfirmation: true,
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isLoggedIn() {
      return this.$store.getters[`auth/${IS_LOGGED_IN}`];
    },
  },
  methods: {
    showLogOutModal() {
      this.modal.show = true;
    },
    onModalClose(confirmation = false) {
      this.modal.show = false;
      if (confirmation === false) return;
      this.logOut();
    },
    logOut() {
      this.$store.dispatch(`auth/${LOG_OUT}`);
      this.$router.push({ name: 'Login' });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And that test works as expected:

```
it('After confirmation of the action user is logged out and redirected to login page', async () => {
    const actions = {
      [LOG_OUT]: jest.fn(),
    };
    await store.hotUpdate({ modules: { auth: { ...auth, actions } } });
    const mockedRouter = {
      push: jest.fn(),
    };
    const wrapper = createWrapper(Header, {
      data: () => ({ modal: { show: true } }),
      mocks: {
        $route: {},
        $router: mockedRouter,
      },
    });
    const mockedLogOutMethod = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'logOut');
    await wrapper.find('.button-yes').trigger('click');
    // the method's called
    expect(mockedLogOutMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // the method performs log out and redirect
    expect(actions[LOG_OUT]).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockedRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'Login' });
  });
```

But this one doesn't, though during it the `data` of the component is changed and we see it on the component's child prop (`'show'` turns to be `true`), thus the method is called indeed, but `toHaveBeenCalled()` can't detect the fact:

```
it("Show modal with confirmation when 'log out' button was clicked", async () => {
    const wrapper = createWrapper(Header);
    const mockedShowModalMethod = jest.spyOn(wrapper .vm, 'showLogOutModal');
    const modal = wrapper.findComponent(Modal);
    // the modal is hidden initially
    expect(modal.props('show')).toBe(false);
    await wrapper.find('.button-log-out').trigger('click');
    // after 'log out' button is clicked the modal appears
    expect(modal.props('show')).toBe(true);
    expect(mockedShowModalMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(wrapper.find('.modal-confirmation').exists()).toBe(true);
  });
```

I found a workaround for that:

```
...    
const mockedShowModalMethod = jest.spyOn(Header.methods, 'showLogOutModal');
const wrapper = createWrapper(Header);
....
```

However, I wanna find out the reason of this behavior, what do I miss here? I have another test suites, where my initial assertion with `jest.spyOn()` works out as well as in the first test here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference between `logOut` and `showLogOutModal` methods is how they are used.

`logOut` is called as regular method:

```
this.logOut();
```

And `showLogOutModal` is passed as a callback:

```
  <v-btn
    v-if="isLoggedIn"
    class="button-log-out"
    text
    @click="showLogOutModal"
```

`this.showLogOutModal` is mocked with `jest.spyOn` after `this.showLogOutModal` is read to to be used as event handler, so a spy doesn't affect anything.

This would likely be fixed by forcing a re-render after replacing `wrapper.vm.showLogOutModal` with a spy:

```
const mockedShowModalMethod = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'showLogOutModal');
await wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate();
```

But a workaround listed in the question is the recommended way to do this:

```
const mockedShowModalMethod = jest.spyOn(Header.methods, 'showLogOutModal');
const wrapper = createWrapper(Header);
```

Comment: this forceUpdate() after spyOn saved my life today

Comment: Same for me. Strange though, I never have to do this but for this particular component I somehow do have to.

Comment: @paddotk This means that original implementation has been already used at the time of spyOn call

Comment: `Header.methods` only works for options-API, is there a way to use it with a `@Component export default class ... extend Vue` in Typescript?

Comment: @MushyPeas did you ever get a solution for this with composition api?

Comment: Sorry, no update from my side.

Comment: @SamWillis The first snippet with `jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm` may work depending on the case, but if it's not then that's it. Composition api enforces testing the behaviour instead of implemenation. If some part of a comp needs to be mocked, it likely needs to be extracted to another unit (composable or component), just for testability reasons