# Use sinon spy on Vue on a function on a component

Tags: vue.js, sinon

I'm writting a unit test that first runs some code outside a component, but a function on a component will eventually be executed because of that call. The code is working correctly but the tests are failing.

I'm writting a test that instantiates a component with `var mycomponent = new Component()`

Then I create the Spy With `var sinon.spy(mycomponent, 'functionname')`

When I run the test, I can see on the logs that the function on the component is being called,  but my assert says it's not being called.

The component on the test is being run as a shallowMount, I wonder if that might make a difference.

My questions would be:

- How can I spy on a function on a component when the function that eventually triggers the function on the component is not in the component
- What's the best way to assert with sinon

Comment: You shouldn't instantiate components directly, they should be instantiated by a renderer. There is no best way, it's that you can spy and assert them, or not. It's unknown what's the problem because the question doesn't contain the code to reproduce it.

Comment: Related question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61859423/why-doesnt-jest-spyon-sometimes-work-on-a-vue-components-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to spy on the wrapper that I had on the component. Using .spy on wrapper.vm fixed the issue